# Delete connections in aws documentdb

Tags: mongodb, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

In aws documentDb is there a way to delete open connections from mongo cli?

When I run

```
db.serverStatus()
```

I see there are about 1k connections, I am trying to delete those. I tried using

```
db.adminCommand( { killSessions: []})
```

Is there a command that I can use or do I need to restart the cluster or block IP of application that has active connection.

Comment: I doubt so, dropConnections was added in mongo 4.2, and documentdb is only 4.0

Comment: You can use the killOp operation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/user_diagnostics.html#user_diagnostics-query_terminating).